# Show Print Dialog Box

Tags: excel, vba

I want Excel to show me the `Print Dialog Box` so that I can select a printer before printing.

I have this code

```
Private Sub PrintButton_Click()
    Feuil2.Activate
    Feuil2.Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 0.5
    
    Columns("B:XFD").EntireColumn.autofit
    
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

But, it shows me the below error on `Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show` line.

[image]

**Translated from French**: `Compilation error - Expected function or variable`

Comment: nothing wrong with your code. The error is somewhere else.

Comment: it looks like i need an art function or an other thing that can call up the application dialogbox. i added the screenshot of the  error message

Comment: Can you share the complete code.. Best is to click on "Debug Menu" and click on "Compile Project". It will tell you where the error is.

Comment: That's my entire code and it always highlights the Word Application in this Code

Comment: Nothing wrong with the line. Unless French version is the cause. What happens when you replace `Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show` with `Application.Dialogs(8).Show`

Comment: Can you also check somethng for me. Click on Tools menu -> References. Do you see any missing references?

Comment: exactly the same as before. What i can't understand is that on other files, this code works but on this file it doesn't :-(

Comment: May I see the file?

Comment: how do i share the file?

Comment: Upload it in free file sharing site like www.wikisend.com, dropbox, onedrive etc and share the link here. Ensure that you delete any confidential data if any